# How does Debian or Linux in general assign device-names like /dev/sdX on ZFS?

Tags: debian, udev, devices, disk

I have three identical servers, all three same cabeling and correctly placed hard-disk. Allthough one of the server got `/dev/sdg /dev/sdh` for the sata-ssds while the other two servers got them on `/dev/sda /dev/sdb` - Im using Proxmox with ZFS.

The SATA-SSDs are connected onBoard (SATA-Cabeling to Board) while the Hard-Disks are connected to a SAS-HBA via Single Cable (SAS).

How do that names get assigned? Serialnumber? Couldnt find valid information that helped me here. And is there a way to change the devicenames after installation in Debian + ZFS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `/dev/sd*` names are simply assigned in detection order, which may vary from one boot to the next if storage driver module loading order is not exactly the same each time, or if disks are plugged or unplugged. The current wisdom is to use something else in your configuration:

- in `/etc/fstab`, you could use the `UUID=` or `LABEL=` syntax instead of device names
- if you're using LVM, it already includes a mechanism to auto-discover physical volumes regardless of device names, and to present the logical volumes using paths that are guaranteed to be persistent
- if using software RAID, it likewise includes a mechanism to find the RAID members based on what's actually on the disk, not by their device names
- if using multipathed SAN LUNs, `device-mapper-multipath` will auto-discover the individual `/dev/sd*` paths and build a persistent device name for accessing the disk using all those paths, either by WWID, by auto-generated persistent names or by customizable names according to your preference
- depending on what exactly you're looking for, you may find the disks/partitions named in a suitable way using the symbolic links in `/dev/disk/by-*/` directories:

  - `/dev/disk/by-id/*` by disk model name and serial number
  - `/dev/disk/by-uuid/*` by filesystem UUIDs (effectively equivalent to the `/etc/fstab` UUID= syntax for uses that do not involve `/etc/fstab`)
  - `/dev/disk/by-label/*` by filesystem labels (effectively equivalent to the `/etc/fstab` LABEL= syntax for uses that do not involve `/etc/fstab`)
  - `/dev/disk/by-path/*` by hardware device path: "bus X, slot Y, function Z, controller slot N" (might be useful if you want a cabling-based name)
  - on GPT-partitioned disks, partitions can also be found using `/dev/disk/by-partuuid/*` and `/dev/disk/by-partlabel/*`

Some distributions (e.g. SuSE if I recall correctly) may also have a udev-rule-based mechanism that will tie a particular `/dev/sd*` to a disk with a particular serial number or other identifying information when it's first seen by the OS. Debian does not have that.

When booting Debian, the disk controller for the root filesystem is loaded first when the system is still running on initramfs. If your system uses just one disk controller (e.g. AHCI SATA on a desktop, or a hot-plug aware SAS hardware RAID controller on a rack-mount server) it usually detects all the disks connected to it in some stable order (driver-specific, e.g. by SATA connector number or hot-plug slot order) and that's the end of it: such ordering *may* be quite stable.

But if you have multiple different storage controllers, you may have a headache as `systemd`-based start-up process is not guaranteed to have any persistent deterministic order, meaning that small time differences in an earlier part of boot process may change the ordering of latter parts. And at boot time, many things will be happening in parallel, so you should not rely on implicit ordering anyway.

[ZFS FAQ has quite a bit to say about choosing the right kind of device names on Linux](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Project%20and%20Community/FAQ.html#selecting-dev-names-when-creating-a-pool-linux). Basically:

- use `/dev/sd*` for small development/test setups only
- for small pools (less than about 10 disks), use `/dev/disk/by-id/*`
- for larger pools, the optimal solution is to [set up an `/etc/zfs/vdev.conf` file](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Project%20and%20Community/FAQ.html#setting-up-the-etczfsvdev_idconf-file) to create nice short names that still reflect the underlying hardware layout
- alternative solution for large pools is `/dev/disk/by-path/*` although the names will be long and cumbersome.

Fortunately, [changing the names on an existing pool is not difficult](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Project%20and%20Community/FAQ.html#changing-dev-names-on-an-existing-pool): it's basically just exporting and re-importing the pool, while specifying the new name scheme on import.

For example, if your pool is named `zfspool`, you could export it and then re-import using `/dev/disk/by-id/*` names like this:

```
# <prepare pool for export, i.e. unmount mount points or stop VMs as necessary>
zpool export zfspool
zpool import -d /dev/disk/by-id zfspool
# <resume using the pool>
```

(This sort of suggests that ZFS actually may have a similar auto-discovery system as e.g. Linux LVM; it's just that the discovery happens on importing the pool, instead of at every startup.)

Comment: Thanks! So does that autodiscover (first in first name) really account on every boot? Im having zfs mirror on proxmox servers and wouldnt it be a bad idea to get a new name on every boot or maybe on a boot? So it seems to be, that the keep the names after installing the os. how do I check udev rules they may created to get always the same device name?

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Comment: Please see my edit... and please edit the question to add some mention that ZFS is involved, as that's an important bit of information in this case that should make this question more easily findable for others in similar situations.

Comment: one last thing, thanks for the hint with ZFS export and import. But I was wondering if I could change the names associated to the "Disk/by-id" - background information on this is, that all exisiting hosts (3) should have the same device names in terms of automation etc. if one host has different /dev/sd* names then you cant automate things like setting up all the other disks of the system via scripts etc. it would be bad to have on host have a different naming on devices. Im sorry for the multiple questions, but I kinda missed how I can do that.

Comment: Don't use the `/dev/sd*` names in the automation scripts either - use whatever `/dev/disk/by-*` is most appropriate to the task in question.